# Why I cannot match certain string with ( | ) in regex

Tags: regex, bash, glob

I have a question about matching a pattern of string

I want copy certain file with some identification characters

For example:

```
20190108JPYUSDabced.csv
20190108CHNUSDabced.csv
20190108IJKUSDabcde.csv
```

So I want to used command to just copy the first 2 files

```
cp 20190108(JPY|CHN)USDabced.csv
```

Does not work.

Received error:
    -bash: syntax error near unexpected token ‘(‘

Comment: `cp` doesn't accept regular expressions. You'll need to approach this some other way, but it's hard to offer much help without more information.

Comment: Relevant and likely helpful: [How do you use regular expressions with the cp command in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/441422/how-do-you-use-regular-expressions-with-the-cp-command-in-linux)

Comment: You can use this with `extglob`: `cp 20190108@(JPY|CHN)USDabced.csv destination`.

Answer (score 6):

`bash` brace expansion is for this

```
$ cp 20190108{JPY,CHN}USDabced.csv
```